# Disable an array of dates in a datepicker on Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, date, datepicker, calendar

I've got two calendars in a form. One is a starting date, and the other is the ending date. I'm using the 'ng-pick-datetime' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) to have a cross-browser calendar picker.

My goal is to block **from date 0 (1st Jan 1970) to the date selected in the starting date calendar**, in the ending date calendar picker.

So the thing here is to make sure the ending date is after the starting date.

For this, ng-pick-datetime' picker has the [disabledDates] property, which is waiting for an array of Dates that shouldn't be selectable.

What I'm trying is to bind this property to my array of forbidden dates, which is created in a function when the form is created, and also every time the ending date calendar gets focus.

I'm printing my array of forbidden dates to check if it is created correctly and if the dates included in it are between date 0 and the starting date selected. I looks like this part is working fine.

I don't get any browser console error. Just have the ending date calendar picker not blocking any date.

This is my template code:

```
<div class="input-control col-sm-6" [class.has-error]="startDate.invalid && startDate.dirty">
        <label class="control-label" for="startDate">Starting Date *</label>
        <owl-date-time
          [(ngModel)]="data.startDate"
          [dateFormat]="'DD-MM-YYYY'"
          [inputId]="'startDate'"
          [placeHolder]="'dd-mm-aaaa'"
          [type]="'calendar'"
          [dataType]="'date'"
          [autoClose]="'true'"
          id="startDate"
          name="startDate"
          #startDate="ngModel"
          [disabled]="!paramsService.isSolicitante()"
          [hideClearButton]
          required>
        </owl-date-time >
</div>

<div class="input-control col-sm-6" [class.has-error]="endDate.invalid && endDate.dirty">
        <label class="control-label" for="endDate">Ending Date *</label>
        <owl-date-time
          [(ngModel)]="data.endDate"
          [dateFormat]="'DD-MM-YYYY'"
          [inputId]="'endDate'"
          [placeHolder]="'dd-mm-aaaa'"
          [type]="'calendar'"
          [dataType]="'date'"
          [autoClose]="'true'"
          id="endDate"
          name="endDate"
          #endDate="ngModel"
          [disabled]="!paramsService.isSolicitante()"
          [hideClearButton]="!paramsService.isSolicitante()"
          [disabledDates]="'forbiddenDates'"
          (onFocus)="getForbiddenEndDates()"
          required>
        </owl-date-time >
</div>

//printing of selected date values:
<div class="col-sm-6">{{ data.startDate}}</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">{{ data.endDate}}</div>

{{ this.forbiddenDates }} //printing of the dates array to check it
```

And this is the component code (typescript), just the part that matters here:

```
forbiddenDates: Date[] = [];

ngAfterViewInit(): void { this.getForbiddenEndDates(); }


// This creates an array of Dates from the beginning of all times to the value of startDate
getForbiddenEndDates(): void {
let dateZero: Date = new Date(0);
let forbiddenDates: Date[] = [];
while (dateZero <= this.data.startDate){
  forbiddenDates.push(new Date(dateZero));
  dateZero.setDate(dateZero.getDate() + 1);
}
this.forbiddenDates = forbiddenDates;
}
```

[Screenshot of the form and the forbidden dates array printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaSpt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself. It seems that this [disabledDates] template property doesn't change dynamically, so it's just for a fixed array of dates.

The solution is much simpler. Add this template property to the endDate input field:

```
[min]="data.startDate"
```